# Python flask app which returns list of files

Tags: python, flask, httpserver

I have a basic flask app which is used to get logs from pods. I want to use send_from_directory when the query is not complete. I do not want to create a zip file and list it rather I would like to list the logs files that are generated with the query.

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask import request
import http.server
import socketserver
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

app = Flask(__name__)
# write route for a namespace completely
@app.route('/logs')
def hello_world():
umgebung = request.args.get('umgebung', None)
product = request.args.get('product', None)
product_type = request.args.get('product_type', None)
output = (subprocess.check_output(['cmd', '/c', f'oc logs --tail=-1 -n awl-{umgebung} -l product={product},type={product_type}'])).decode();
if not output:
    output_as = (subprocess.check_output(['cmd', '/c', f'oc logs --tail=-1 -n awl-{umgebung} -l product={product},type=as'])).decode();
    output_db = (subprocess.check_output(['cmd', '/c', f'oc logs --tail=-1 -n awl-{umgebung} -l product={product},type=db'])).decode();
    output_as_file = open ("logs/output_as_log.log","w")
    output_db_file = open ("logs/output_db_log.log","w")
    output_as_file.write(output_as)
    output_db_file.write(output_db)
    path= 'logs'
    return send_from_directory(path, output_as_file,as_attachment=True) #HERE I DO NOT UNDERSTNAD WHAT SHOUDL  BE GIVEN       
output = "<br />".join(output.split("\n"))   
return output
```

I am creating the log files under the logs folder within the project folder. How can i display all the files in the folder `log` ? So that it can  be downloaded with a click?

Clarification for the close Votes!!

The app should return the files from a particular folder. But the `send_fron_directory` is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list all files using [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) or the [pathlib library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). The result can then be output within a template.
Then you add a new route which expects the file name as a parameter and delivers the file from the folder via [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory). You can pass the name of the file as a path within a [rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).
As far as I understand you correctly, the following example should meet your requirements.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/logs/')
def logs():
    filenames = os.listdir('logs')
    return render_template('logs.html', files=filenames)

@app.route('/logs/<path:filename>')
def log(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        os.path.abspath('logs'),
        filename,
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

The following template should be added under `templates/logs.html` in the application directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Logfiles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
    {% for file in files %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('log', filename=file) }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it did not work for me: `Could not build url for endpoint 'logs' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'hello_world' instead?` i have the template copied to the folder templates.

Comment: @Vini Sorry, my mistake. I have updated my answer. In the template it should read as follows: `<a href="{{url_for('log', filename=file)}}>`. The specification of the end point in `url_for` refers to the identifier of the route. You are right. The template must be saved under `templates/logs.html`. I'm sorry.

Comment: I tried log as well, but with the same error. As you can see in my code, the return is when the URL is not completely valid.

Comment: @Vini I can't explain myself. In fact, the URL could not be created because the endpoint "logs" does not take any parameters. Since the URL refers to "log" it should work, which it does for me. The rule, the argument of the function and the parameter passed to url_for are called filename. This means that all requirements are met.

Comment: For instance I m trying to call the URL http:localhost:5000/logs?umgebung=sit&product=simethig, So it enters the no output part in my script, but the render_template is not rendered. i get a 500 on browser and the error whoch I posted above on the console.

Comment: I used a diff name for the function. It works as expected :-)

Comment: @Vini As an explanation: the first argument of url_for relates to the name of the function of the route / endpoint. If it works, I hope you continue to have fun. Sorry again that it didn't work right away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time here and your explanation. this is my first time in this python world!

Comment: @Vini You can ask anytime. I think the python documentation is very good and I recommend [this one](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) for flask. There are also other useful articles on the topic of flask on the site.